# Conditional row select with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select a sub-set of a pandas dataframe `df` where the column `text` has the value `'0.0, 0.0'`. I thought the command for this would be `df.ix[df['text'] == "0.0, 0.0"]` but this returns

```
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but symbol literal found.
   df.ix[df['text'] == "0.0, 0.0"]
            ^
<console>:1: error: unclosed character literal
   df.ix[df['text'] == "0.0, 0.0"]
                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you modify any part of the error message?

Comment: No, I did not change the error message

Comment: It works fine when I try it. Can you add versions of your Python/pandas installations, which environment you are using etc?

Comment: .. are you sure you're using Python and not Scala?

Comment: @DSM I just realized I'm in a Zeppelin notebook and hadn't specified that it should be using the Py interpreter. My bad! Will question delete in 5 mins

Comment: @DannyDavidLeybzon Or you could post your own answer to the question, and leave it as a resource for people who might encounter the same problem in the future.

Comment: @DavidZ probably a good call; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) pointed out, the error appears to be an error from the Scala programming language. This is because I was using a Zeppelin Notebook, and had failed to specify that the code should be interpreted with the pyspark interpreter. After specifying the interpreter, the code worked as expected.